# How to optimize gas cost of specific function on solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, gas-limit

source code:https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x09850b9d949c71e1d9b7e9acaa3645ac5b63d6bb#code

This is a betting smart contract, I have a problem with the allocated prize. The gas cost is very high, it depends on the number of winners.

this is the function for allocating prize:

```
function allocatePrizes(uint _gameId, uint16 teamWinner) public onlyAgent {
        Game storage game = gameInfo[_gameId];
        require(bettingActive == false);
        address[1000] memory winners;
        address[1000] memory draw;
        //We have to create a temporary in memory array with fixed size
        //Let's choose 1000
       
        totalBets = 0;
        count = 0;
        
        //We loop through the player array to check who selected the winner team
        for( i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
            address playerAddress = players[i];
            //If the player selected the winner team
            //We add his address to the winners array
            if(playerInfo[playerAddress].teamSelected == teamWinner){
                winners[count] = playerAddress;
                count++;
            }
            playerInfo[playerAddress]._state = PlayerStatus.Not_Joined;
        }


        //We define which bet sum is the Loser one and which one is the winner
        if ( teamWinner == 1){
            totalBets = totalBetsOne + totalBetsTwo;
        //We loop through the array of winners, to give ethers to the winners
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
            // Check that the address in this fixed array is not empty
            if(winners[i] != address(0)){
             add = winners[i];
             bets = playerInfo[add].amountBet;

            // token.transfer(winners[j],  (bets*(10000+(LoserBet*fee /WinnerBet)))/10000 );
             rewards = (bets*(10000-550 *(totalBets / totalBetsOne))) / 10000;
            _pendingBalance[add] += rewards;
            }
           
        }
        for(i=0; i < players.length; i++){
            add = players[i];
            if(players[i] != address(0)){
                delete playerInfo[add].amountBet;
                delete playerInfo[add].teamSelected;
                delete playerInfo[add];
            }
        }  
        bettingActive = true;
        gameInfo[_gameId] = Game(_gameId, State.Finished);
        game.state == State.Finished;
        players.length = 0; // Delete all the players array
        totalBets = 0;
        totalBetsOne = 0;
        totalBetsTwo = 0;  
        }
        else if(teamWinner == 2){
            totalBets = totalBetsOne + totalBetsTwo;  
        //We loop through the array of winners, to give ethers to the winners
        for( i = 0; i < count; i++){

            // Check that the address in this fixed array is not empty
            if(winners[i] != address(0)){
             add = winners[i];
             bets = playerInfo[add].amountBet;

            // token.transfer(winners[k],  (bets*(10000+(LoserBet*fee /WinnerBet)))/10000 );
            rewards = (bets*(10000-550 *(totalBets / totalBetsTwo))) / 10000; 
            _pendingBalance[add] += rewards;
            }
        }
    
        for(i=0; i < players.length; i++){
            add = players[i];
            if(players[i] != address(0)){
                delete playerInfo[add].amountBet;
                delete playerInfo[add].teamSelected;
                delete playerInfo[add];
            }
        }
        bettingActive = true;
        gameInfo[_gameId] = Game(_gameId, State.Finished);
        game.state == State.Finished;
        players.length = 0; // Delete all the players array
        totalBets = 0;
        totalBetsOne = 0;
        totalBetsTwo = 0;                
        }
        else if(teamWinner == 3){
            totalBets = totalBetsOne + totalBetsTwo;
            //We loop through the player array to check who selected the winner team
        num = 0;
        for( i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
            add = players[i];

            if(playerInfo[add].teamSelected == 1||playerInfo[add].teamSelected == 2){
                draw[num] = add;
                num++;
            }
        }
        //We loop through the array of winners, to give ethers to the winners
        for( i = 0; i < num; i++){
            // Check that the address in this fixed array is not empty
            if(draw[i] != address(0)){
             add = draw[i];
             bets = playerInfo[add].amountBet;

            // token.transfer(draw[m], (bets*(fee))/10000 );
            
            rewards = (bets*(10000-fee))/10000;
            _pendingBalance[add] += rewards;
        }
        bettingActive = true;
        gameInfo[_gameId] = Game(_gameId, State.Finished);
        game.state == State.Finished;
        delete playerInfo[add];
        delete playerInfo[add].amountBet;
        delete playerInfo[add].teamSelected;
        playerInfo[add]._state = PlayerStatus.Not_Joined;
        players.length = 0; // Delete all the players array
        totalBetsOne = 0;
        totalBetsTwo = 0;
        totalBets = 0;
        }
       
    }
       
    }
```

can anyone help me to optimize the function?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of simplifying your code.
First two methods that come to mind is implicit statements instead of if statements in your for-loops (i.g. ternary (*test ? result1 : result2*)).

Rethink your logic to optimize; instead of all bets, winners and losers, you break up your votes by type and store them in separate arrays so then you don't need to sort and rebuild your array etc:

```
struct game = {
   address [] teamAVotes;
   address [] teamBVotes;
   address [] teamCVotes;
}
mapping(uint256 => game) games;
mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => uint256)) betForGame;
mapping(uint256 => uint256) betPoolForGame;
mapping(uint256 => bool) betPoolOpen;

function voteNow(uint256 gameId, uint256 vote) public payable {
    require(vote==1 || vote==2 || vote==3);
    require(betPoolOpen[gameId]);
    betForGame[gameId][msg.sender] = msg.value;
    vote==1 ? 
        gameId[gameId].teamAVotes = msg.sender
        : vote==2 ? 
        gameId[gameId].teamBVotes = msg.sender
        :
        gameId[gameId].teamCVotes = msg.sender;
    betPoolForGame[gameId] += msg.value;
}

function payOut(uint256 gameId, uint256 vote) public {
    require(vote==1 || vote==2 || vote==3);
    require(!betPoolOpen[gameId]);
    address [] memory winners = vote==1 ? 
        gameId[gameId].teamAVotes
        : vote==2 ? 
        gameId[gameId].teamBVotes
        :
        gameId[gameId].teamCVotes;
    // now take your fees and divide the part they won
}
```

Last method is using a proxy contract (*eip1967*) or second contract to make an external call, which is always cheaper.
*@openzeppelin/upgrades/contracts/upgradeability/Proxy.sol*

Comment: I have problem with this gameInfo[_gameId].teamMeron = msg.sender; (TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address[] storage ref.
gameInfo[_gameId].teamMeron = msg.sender;)